# Codewars Javascript Problem- my code with a double for loop times out

Tags: javascript, algorithm, loops, sorting

I'm trying to solve a problem on Codewars which involves seeing if one string includes all the letters in a second string. I think I've found a decent solution, but my code times out (12000ms) and I can't figure out why. Could anyone shed some light on this issue?

```
function scramble(str1, str2) {
  let i;
  let j;
  let x = str2.split();
  for (i = 0; i < str1.length; i++) {
    for (j = 0; j < str2.length; j++) {
      if (str1[i] == str2[j]) {
        x.splice(j, 1);
        j--;
      }
    }
  }
  if (x.length == 0) {
    return true;
  } else {
    return false;
  }
}
```

Comment: you are doing `str1[i] == str2[j]`, the line after you are doing `j--` but do not change either `str1` or `str2` so it will always loop with the same index and the same values over and over when it find a match. If you use console log you would easily find out.

Comment: Did you test the accepted answer? If you talk about codewars scramblies then it will give wrong results, at least the last code snippet.

Comment: @maraca i tested it with the false-positive edit i made, the code passed all sample tests but failed a lot of actual tests (all failed with true when false was expected). I checked the codewars comments and the test indeed seems to have issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're adjusting `x` but then referring to `str2` as if it has been changed. Because you never adjust `str2`, you're always comparing the same two letters, so you get stuck in a loop. That's one problem. Then, your question's wording suggests that we're checking if every letter in `str2` is in `str1`, but you're going through every letter in `str1` and checking it against `str2`. `str1` should be the *inner* loop.

```js
function scramble(str1, str2) {
  var x = str2.split("");
  for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < str1.length; j++) {
      if (str1[j] == x[i]) {
        x.splice(i--, 1);
      }
    }
  }
  return x.length === 0;
}

console.log(scramble("dirty rooms", "dormitory"));
console.log(scramble("cat", "dog"));
```

Because `x.length === 0` is already a boolean value, you can just return that. No need for the if statements there. The triple equals checks the variable's type and value, and double equals only checks value. I tend to always use triple when I'm checking against 0 and 1 because you don't want unintended consequences like this:

```js
console.log(false == 0, true == 1);
console.log(false === 0, true === 1);
```

Also, because `i--` means "`i = i - 1` *after* execution",  you can put that directly in your call to `splice`, and it won't execute until after `splice` is finished. `--i`, on the other hand, would be evaluated *before* execution.

This is all great, but using [`indexOf`](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_indexof.asp) is a simpler solution:

```js
function scramble(str1, str2) {
  for (let i = 0; i < str2.length; i++) {
    if (str1.indexOf(str2[i]) == -1) return false;
  }
  return true;
}

console.log(scramble("forty five", "over fifty"));
console.log(scramble("cat", "dog"));
```

Comment: 1. This is O(N * M) and 2. it is not the same logic as seemed to be intended by the asker of the question. scramble("cat", "tca") = true, but scramble("cat", "cata") = false (here your implementation would say true), at least this is what the askers implementation would do if it would have worked.

Comment: @maraca is correct. the code here can be modified a bit to avoid false positive: `function scramble(str1, str2) {
  let i;
  let x = str2.split("");

  for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    if (str1.indexOf(x[i]) == -1) {
      return false;
    } else {
      x.splice(i--, 1);
    }
  }
  return true;
}
` once we do this, it seems to work.

Comment: The code you've provided returns true for scramble("cat", "cata") as well. If that's not correct, I'd be able to help more if I could read the codewars solution. However, it seems like you may have already pieced together what you were looking for here, so don't feel the need to keep updating us if you already have what you want.

Answer (score 2):

If your strings have sizes N and M then your algorithm is O(N*M). You can get O(NlogN + MlogM) by sorting both strings and then do a simple comparison. But you can do even better and get O(N+M) by counting the letters in one string and then see if they are present in the other. E.g. something like this:

```
function scramble(str1, str2) {
  let count = {}
  for (const c of str1) {
    if (!count[c])
      count[c] = 1
    else
      count[c]++
  }
  for (const c of str2) {
    if (!(c in count))
      return false
    count[c]--
  }
  for (let k in count) {
    if (count.hasOwnProperty(k) && count[k] !== 0)
      return false
  }
  return true
}
```

Comment: To test if only a portion of str1 can be rearranged to str2 you just have to change `count[k] !== 0` in the last `if` to `count[k] >= 0`.

Answer (score 2):

You created an infinite loop by both incrementing and decrementing `j`. The value of `j` gets stuck whenever `str1[i] == str2[j]`

Reducing your code snippet to the simplest form would look something like this:

```js
for (j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
  j--;
  console.log(j) // always -1
}
```